# Como obtener datos de un EditText fuera del método OnCreate - Android

Tags: mysql, android-studio, listview, edittext

soy nuevo en esto, paciencia con este post! , estoy intentanto enviar informacion a mi base de datos para que me envie solo lo que necesito, para eso quiero combinar la url por un lado, y el nombre de usuario por el otro, y con todos esos registros, enviarlos a un listview, el problema es que no puedo ya que fuera del Oncreate al EditText me lo toma como null reference, Dejo mi codigo:

```
package com.prueba.kesqui;

+imports..

public class pendientes extends AppCompatActivity
{

    EditText tvuser;
    ListView lv;

    private static String name[];
    private static String desig[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pendientes);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tvuser = findViewById(R.id.tvuser);


        SharedPreferences sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("credentials", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sp.getString("uname","");
        tvuser.setText(name);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

        fetch_data_into_array(lv);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String s = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    String BASE_URL = "http://miwebpersonal.com/json_user_fetch.php?user=";
    String VER = "john";
    String apiurl = BASE_URL + VER;
```

lo que necesito es que BASE_URL se combine con VER y quede algo asi:

"http://miwebpersonal.com/json_user_fetch.php?user=john"
y asi enviar esa info a traves de una api

ya probe con

```
    String BASE_URL = "http://miwebpersonal.com/json_user_fetch.php?user=";
    String VER = "tvuser.getText.toString";
    String apiurl = BASE_URL + VER;
```

y me da el siguiente error: **Method invocation 'getText' will produce 'NullPointerException'**

Aclaración 1: los datos de **tvuser** son de sharedpreferences y vienen desde el login, puedo visualizarlo, pero no puedo tomarlo para formar la sentencia final **String apiurl**

Aclaración 2: de esta forma funciona correctamente, pero solo me trae los datos del usuario escrito en VER

```
    String BASE_URL = "http://miwebpersonal.com/json_user_fetch.php?user=";
    String VER = "john";
    String apiurl = BASE_URL + VER;
```

Desde ya, muchisimas gracias por sus sugerencias!
Atte. Carlos

Comment: Fuera del oncreate... vale, pero tendrá que estar dentro de algún método aun así, no?? Si lo pones fuera de todo método, estarás intentando ejecutar esa línea de código nada más cargarse la clase, incluso antes de que entre al `onCreate`, con lo cual `tvuser` vale `null` pues no ha sido inicializado. Te recomiendo que busques algún tutorial de programación orientada a objetos en Java y aprendas a trabajar con objetos de manera correcta, pues esto es un fallo de base.

Comment: Android no se ejecuta "lineal", si no que hay ciertos métodos que se ejecutan en un orden establecido! En este caso el "*constructor*" es el `onCreate` para las activities, y siempre se entra por ahí. Las variables que están fuera de los métodos (variables de clase) son inicializadas ahí dentro... tú estás intentando usarla antes de que el "*constructor*" se ejecute, ergo las variables están todavía a null!

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. La opción es ponerlos como private static final, pero ahí no puedo combinar, no quiero rendirme, sigo buscando

Comment: No, la opción es ponerlos en un método que llamas cuando lo necesitas, no hacerlos estáticos

Comment: si tuvieras tiempo, me ayudarias a crear ese método?

Comment: Lee [ask], haz el [tour], quita las imágenes y deja el código como texto y estoy seguro de que alguien te podrá ayudar con los problemas que tengas. Te he dado una solución, investiga un poco e intenta hacer algo. Por cierto, sigo sin entender por qué quieres quitarlo del `oncreate` si ahí te funcionaba

Comment: quite las imágenes, si le saco el formato de código, se pierde mucho, sobre tu consulta, nunca lo puse en el oncreate, porque me daba error, hay mas codigo aparte de lo que se ve.

Answer (score 0):

El tratar de obtener el valor dentro de una vista y asignarlo a una variable no es  permitido:

```
String VER = tvuser.getText().toString();
```

la razón principal es que no se ha obtenido la referencia de la vista, es decir no se ha llamado `onCreate()` que es donde obtienes la referencia de la vista:

```
EditText tvuser;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_twitter);

                //Obtene referencia de EditText dentro del Layout fragment_twitter.xml
                tvuser = findViewById(R.id.tvuser);

}
```

lo que debes realizar es un método para posteriormente a la construcción de la UI y la obtención de la referencia, puedas obtener el valor del texto que contiene el `EditText`.

```
private String getTexto(){
    return tvuser.getText().toString();
}
```

Al llamar este método podrás obtener el valor escrito dentro del `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por responder, lo solucione insertando el link dentro de la clase:

```
    public void fetch_data_into_array(View view)
    {

        class  dbManager extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
        {
            protected void onPostExecute(String data)
            {
                try {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
                    JSONObject jo = null;

                    name = new String[ja.length()];
                    desig = new String[ja.length()];


                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        name[i] = jo.getString("apellido");;
                        desig[i] = jo.getString("direccion");

                    }

                    myadapter adptr = new myadapter(getApplicationContext(), name, desig);
                    lv.setAdapter(adptr);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
            {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        data.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();

                    return data.toString();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return ex.getMessage();
                }

            }

        }

        String BASE_URL = "http://miwebpersonal.com/json_user_fetch.php?user=";
        String apiurl = BASE_URL + tvuser.getText();

        dbManager obj=new dbManager();
        obj.execute(apiurl);

    }
```